# Text wrapping onto second line pushing img up in unordered list

Tags: html, css

I've run into this problem a few times and I'm wondering if anyone could offer any assistance.

I've got the following html:

```
<ul>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>Very Long List Item 1</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 2</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100px;
}
ul li img{
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

Is there a way I can get the text to wrap so the image isnt pushed up???

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100px;
}
ul li img{
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>Very Long List Item 1</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 2</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Vertical Align Top to the li

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100px;
}
ul li img{
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>Very Long List Item 1</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 2</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align`

**CSS**

```
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/124/)**

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul li img{
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>Very Long List Item 1</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 2</span></li>
<li><img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/2000px-Smiley.svg.png'/><span>List Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```